# Optional menu item after a submenu not displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a strange problem on an ActionBar I am setting up on a ListActivity.

Here is the XML I use to setup my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_search"
   android:title="@string/search_filter"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_start_date"
   android:title="@string/date_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_end_date"
   android:title="@string/date_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_filters"
   android:title="@string/filters"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText">

  <menu>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_ratings"
            android:title="@string/ratings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_emotions"
            android:title="@string/emotions"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_smi2"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_categories"
            android:title="@string/categories"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
 </menu>

 <item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_search_order"
   android:title="@string/search_order"    
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_order"
   android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />     
</item>

</menu>
```

The menu items `menu_search`, `menu_start_date`, `menu_end_date` and the sub-menu `menu_filters` are working well but impossible to get the menu `menu_search_order` from the physical menu button (nothing happens when I press the button).

So I did a little test to see if the problem is not coming from the submenu, I changed the code and commented the submenu part:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_search"
   android:title="@string/search_filter"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_start_date"
   android:title="@string/date_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_end_date"
   android:title="@string/date_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_filters"
   android:title="@string/filters"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText">

  <!-- <menu>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_ratings"
            android:title="@string/ratings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_emotions"
            android:title="@string/emotions"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_smi2"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_categories"
            android:title="@string/categories"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
 </menu> -->

 <item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_search_order"
   android:title="@string/search_order"    
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_order"
   android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />     
</item>

</menu>
```

After this change, the menu works well and the option is displayed when I push the physical menu button.

So my question is: why is the submenu blocking my last menu to appear in the first case?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue and cannot find solution... looks like I will have to make the menu manually instead of xml in NavigationView ...

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the code in my question is not working but I found the trick to finally make it work.

I just moved my optional menu (initially at the bottom) before the submenu in the XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_search"
   android:title="@string/search_filter"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_start_date"
   android:title="@string/date_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_end_date"
   android:title="@string/date_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_search_order"
   android:title="@string/search_order"    
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_order"
   android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item 
   android:id="@+id/menu_filters"
   android:title="@string/filters"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText">

<menu>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_ratings"
            android:title="@string/ratings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_emotions"
            android:title="@string/emotions"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_smi2"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_categories"
            android:title="@string/categories"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
 </menu>

</item>

</menu>
```

The order here is not important because this menu is the only one I need to see through the physical menu button.

Comment: This is not solution but just workaround for your situation when you don't care about order, but mostly order matter a lot...

Answer (score 0):

So after so many tries I found a way how to make those items display everywhere correctly. So the trick is to put all items to group element with some id and also `android:checkableBehavior="single"` , this is only way I was able to get it to render as defined in xml. If I remove id from first group last two items get merged to previous menu sub items. Quite buggy android menu implementation. It should be reported somewhere, but hopefully someone else will do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/signup_1_identification_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dopkkpokadad"
            android:title="@string/signup_1_identification" />
    </group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/kokopj"
        android:title="@string/signup_6_nationality">
        <menu android:id="@+id/signup_6_nationality_menu">
            <group
                android:id="@+id/signup_6_nationality_group"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/dadceqpovjopeqad"
                    android:title="Hlavna" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/cionno"
                    android:title="Dalsia" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/dkbvyukbadad"
                    android:title="Materinsky Jazyk" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/signup_last_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dafeqpokopqdad"
            android:title="@string/signup_7_religion" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dakopefhpoiueqdad"
            android:title="@string/signup_8_finalization" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

This is how it is rendered correctly from this xml:

[image: This is how it is rendered correctly]

When I remove id from fist group I get back wrong behaviour, last two items gets merged, in some cases they will disappear or other weird stuff happens depending on other layout changes, I believe android menu implementation is just buggy...

[image: When I remove id from fist group I get back wrong behaviour:]